# printf to n column?

Tags: bash, scripting, printf

This:

`dots=$(printf "%0.s." {1..10})`

prints this:

`..........` .

I'd like to know how to get `printf` in Bash to print `.`s up to a specific column position, let's say `30`, where the start column will vary.

For example:

`Add dots ....................`

`Add dots dots ...............`

`Add dots dots dots ..........`

Answer (score 0):

In a shell

```
$ n=30
$ dots=$(printf "%.0s." $(seq $n))
$ echo "$dots"
..............................
```

So:

```
$ n=30
$ str='Add dots '
$ dots=$(printf "%.0s." $(seq $((n-${#str})) ))
$ echo "$str$dots"
Add dots .....................
```

And:

```
$ n=30; str='Add dots dots '; dots=$(printf "%.0s." $(seq $((n-${#str})) )); echo "$str$dots"
Add dots dots ................
```

In a function:

```
$ dots(){ printf "%s" "$2"; printf "%.0s." $( seq $(($1-${#2})) );echo; }
$ dots 30 "Add dots dots dots "
Add dots dots dots ...........

$ dots 40 "Add dots dots dots "
Add dots dots dots .....................

$ dots 33 "we hold these truths "
we hold these truths ............
```

Comment: `add dots` could just as well be 'we hold these truths` or 'I am sam` The point is that the start column will vary, but I always want to add '.` from the end of the string to the 30 column position.

Comment: @marshki Is the last command what you want?

Comment: Will test and let you know @Issac.